# How to override the properties of a single glyph inside a Bokeh plot?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have the following simple example, and I would like to reset the colour property of one of the circles to be red, as a separate process, after the renderer is initialised.

```
from bokeh.plotting import show

x = [2, 4, 8, 5, 9, 3]
y = [4, 8, 2, 7, 4, 6]
id = ['1001', '1002', '1003', '1004', '1005', '1006']

cds = ColumnDataSource(data={'x': x, 'y': y, 'id': id})

p = figure(width=300, height=200)
p.circle(x='x', y='y', source=cds, size=5, color='green')

# This is my issue?!
#p.circle[0].color = 'red'

show(p)
```

I'm aware that I can use the following API to achieve the result, but that is not an option considering what I would like to do next.

```
selected_circle = Circle(fill_alpha=1, fill_color="firebrick", line_color=None)
nonselected_circle = Circle(fill_alpha=0.2, fill_color="blue", line_color="firebrick")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the color in a separate step, you can just hide the previous circle with a new one:

```
x = [2, 4, 8, 5, 9, 3]
y = [4, 8, 2, 7, 4, 6]
id_ = ['1001', '1002', '1003', '1004', '1005', '1006']

cds = ColumnDataSource(data={'x': x, 'y': y, 'id': id_})

p = figure(width=300, height=200)
p.circle(x='x', y='y', source=cds, size=5, color='green')

# Coordinate of the red circle that will hide the first one:
red_x = x[0]
red_y = y[0]

p.circle(x=red_x, y=red_y, size=5, color='red')

show(p)
```

But tbh I would prefer to specify the color from the beginning, like the option below.

```
x = [2, 4, 8, 5, 9, 3]
y = [4, 8, 2, 7, 4, 6]
id_ = ['1001', '1002', '1003', '1004', '1005', '1006']
color = ['red'] + ['green']*5  # add a color flag

cds = ColumnDataSource(data={'x': x, 'y': y, 'id': id_, 'color': color})

p = figure(width=300, height=200)

p.circle(x='x', y='y', size=5, source=cds, color='color')

show(p)
```

**EDIT**

In the example below, you can change the color of a circle with a button.
It can be tested in a jupyter notebook.

```
# Modified to work with Bokeh (v3.2.0) and JupyterLab (v3.3.2)

from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CheckboxButtonGroup, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, output_notebook
import pandas as pd
output_notebook()

def create_plot(doc):
    
    # create fake data
    x = [2, 4, 8, 5, 9, 3]
    y = [4, 8, 2, 7, 4, 6]
    id_ = ['1001', '1002', '1003', '1004', '1005', '1006']
    color = ['red'] + ['green']*5
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'ids': id_, 'color': color})

    # create column data source
    cds = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

    # create figure
    p = figure(width=300, height=200)
    p.circle(x='x', y='y', size=5, source=cds, color='color')

    # Create widget (checkbox button)
    checkbox_button_group = CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=id_, active=[0])

    # Update the colors after a click on an id
    checkbox_button_group.js_on_change("active", CustomJS(code="""
        console.log('checkbox_button_group: active=' + this.active, this.toString())
        """))

    def set_col(row, red_ids):
        color = 'red' if row in red_ids else 'green'
        return color

    def update_data(df, red_ids=None):
        if red_ids is None:
            red_ids = []
        
        df['color'] = df['ids'].apply(lambda x: set_col(x, red_ids))
        cds.data = df

    def update(attr, old, new):
        red_ids = [checkbox_button_group.labels[i] for i in checkbox_button_group.active]
        update_data(df, red_ids)

    checkbox_button_group.on_change('active', update)

    # display button & plot in a column
    doc.add_root(column(checkbox_button_group, p))

show(create_plot, notebook_url="localhost:8891")
```

Comment: I will eventually have to do this through some kind of a callback. Let's say I have a button that says `Make Circle [1] Red`, and once that is pressed, the targeted circle will become red.

With your technique, I might be able to manipulate the data field for index [1] and set the colour in the 'color' column, at the second row.

Comment: Exactly, with a callback you can update the datasource, so what you are describing will work. I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: This didn't run in a jupyter notebook. Got bunch of `GET` errors. Is it possible to modify the solution so I can run it with `bokeh serve --show test-app.py`.

Comment: Got your solution to work both in a `jupyterlab notebook` and as a standalone server. Will keep your solution as the valid one, and my alternative might be just as useful for anyone trying to solve similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I was not able to run the valid solution, so I created an alternative solution myself.

Here is a demonstration of changing a single glyph with a button and a javascript callback using bokeh.

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure
from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, layout
from bokeh import events
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Switch, ColumnDataSource

output_notebook()

x = [2, 4, 8, 5, 9, 3]
y = [4, 8, 2, 7, 4, 6]
id = ['1001', '1002', '1003', '1004', '1005', '1006']
color = ['green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green']
state = [0,0,0,0,0,0]

cds = ColumnDataSource(data={'x': x, 'y': y, 'id': id, 'color': color, 'state': state})

p = figure(width=300, height=200)
renderer = p.circle(x='x', y='y', source=cds, size=7, color='color')

# This is my issue?!
#p.circle.x[0] = 1
#renderer.glyph.fill_color='red'

bt = Button(label='Make me Red!', width=200)
sw = Switch(active=True)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=cds, my_state_switch=sw, trigger_obj=bt), code="""
    const f = cb_obj.event_name;
    const label = trigger_obj.label;
    
    let my_trigger_state = my_state_switch.active;
    
    console.log('DEBUG: IN_TRIGGER_STATE: ' + my_trigger_state);
    
    let target_color = 'black'
    
    if (my_trigger_state){
        // Has been changed from green to red.
        trigger_obj.label = 'Make me green!';
        target_color = 'red';
        my_trigger_state = false;
    }else{
        // Has been changed from red to green already.
        trigger_obj.label = 'Make me red!';
        target_color = 'green';
        my_trigger_state = true;
    }
    
    source.data.color[1] = target_color;
    console.log('DEBUG: OUT_TRIGGER_STATE: ' + my_trigger_state);
          
    // Update externals.
    my_state_switch.active = my_trigger_state;
    source.change.emit()
""")

bt.js_on_event(events.ButtonClick, callback)
row = row(bt, sw)
column = column(row, p)

show(column)
```